# Make home page 100% of the height of screen

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, sass

I have a home page/landing page which has a image(canvas) and a carousel at the bottom of it.

I want to the entire page to be 100% of the screen size with following distributions:

```
navbar:10% height
canvas/image:60% height
carousel:30% height
```

How can we ensure this distribution with overall page taking 100% of screen height without a scroll bar ?

Currently I have fixed height of 400px for the canvas, which offcourse messes up the structure on different screens

Also I want to make sure screens of different sizes are supported (Desktop, laptops, monitors etc). Its fine if mobile screens are not supported however would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, modify the below code according to your needs.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #nav {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        height: 10%;
        width: 100%;
        background: red;
    }
    #can {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 30%;
        height: 60%;
        width: 100%;
        background: blue;
    }
    #car {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 30%;
        width: 100%;
        background: green;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
        Test Nav Div
    </div>

    <div id="can">
        Test Canvas Div
    </div>  

    <div id="car">
        Test Carousel Div
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```